# Calling a method with named arguments causes “multiple values for argument” error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get my youtube statistics from Youtube Data API, and then put all the statistics on an image.

When I'm trying to pass the arguments to my image maker function,

```py
# vid_stats and c_stats are dictionaries, 
# but in them, there's no "video_title" key or anything
statimager.create_image(video_title="Video title", video_stats=vid_stats, channel_stats=c_stats)
```

it gives me this TypeError:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_Prog\Python\ytstatupdater\ytstatupdater.py", line 118, in <module>
    statimager.create_image(video_title="Video title", video_stats=vid_stats, channel_stats=c_stats)
TypeError: create_image() got multiple values for argument 'video_title'
```

And here's the definition of create_image() function:

```py
def create_image(video_title, video_stats, channel_stats):
```

In this function, I only use these arguments to put the `video_title`, and the strings in `video_stats` and `channel_stats` to a string array.

I don't really understand why does the program wants to pass multiple values as video_title, as video_title is a single string object.

I'm working in Python 3.9.1.

Comment: What does `video_title` contain exactly? Can you verify it it by printing and show us what you got?

Comment: I verified it many times in python console, it shows a string.

Comment: Is the `create_image` a static method of `statimager` or a method of an instance `statimager`?

Comment: I think you need a [mcve]. It's a bit hard to get the full context of the problem with just these pieces.

Comment: `create_image` is a method of an instance StatImage(), but in this instance, there aren't any `video_title`, `video_stats`, `channel_stats`, `vid_stats` or `c_stats` object.

Comment: Did you forget to put `self` as the first argument for the `create_image()` method?

Comment: All methods need to have `self` as first parameter, which seems to be missing from the method `create_image`

Comment: @ted-klein-bergman Oooooh my goood, and really... I forgot this thing only :D thanks...

Comment: @aerijman `def create_image(video_title:str, video_stats:dict, channel_stats:dict):` is correct type annotation and is good practice. `def f()->(a:a, b:b, etc)` is not valid.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Thank you for the correction. I deleted the misleading comment.

Answer (score 0):

So in the comments, @ted-klein-bergman mentioned that I forgot to put `self` in the definition as first parameter.
I've put that in the definition and it works now.